# How to update firebase realtime database automatically at a certain time daily in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to reset the database values every day at 11:59:59 PM sharp.

Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run daily and perform the required database updates.

Comment: is there any easy tutorial which can explain how to use cloud functions?? I' not getting much from that link

Comment: Start at the very top of the documentation to learn how the product works.  I linked you to the page that is specific to scheduled functions, because that's what you'll want to use.